# Why does the debugger in this bloc of code displays a recursive assignment error?

Tags: maple

```
cube := 0;                       
nombre_premiers := 0;
while cube^3 <= 10^4 do
    if isprime(cube) then
        nombres_premiers := nombres_premiers+1 
        end if; 
    cube := cube+1 
    end do;
```

Can someone explain to me why I can a recursive assignment error?

The program is basically incrementing a counter for the number of primes equal or less to 10,000.

I was thinking maybe it has to do with the fact that at the end of each line, I shift-enter so the code is processed only on one line but I am really not sure.

Comment: NVM i forgot  a s in my variable name lmao

Answer (score 0):

You have used a different spelling in your initialization,

```
nombre_premiers := 0
```

while elsewhere you use the name `nombres_premiers`.

Since `nombres_premiers` is just an unassigned name, the line,

```
nombres_premiers := nombres_premiers+1;
```

is going to cause that problem.